# joining two tables with nullable foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created two tables below, and `FK_TypeID` is nullable in this case. I want to write a query returning me the *join* of two tables.

if `FK_TypeID` is *NULL* for a certain row, the `TypeName` is also *NULL*. I am not sure how to go about creating such join statement?

```
[Actions]
ActionsID
Date
Message
FK_TypeID //links to the table below

[Type]
TypeID
TypeName
```

My current statment looks like this and it simply skips *NULL*  `FK_TypeID` rows

```
SELECT        *
FROM            Actions 
INNER JOIN      TypeName ON Actions.FK_TypeID = [Type].TypeID
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You just need to use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT Actions.Date, Actions.Message, Type.TypeName
FROM Actions
    LEFT JOIN Type 
        ON Type.TypeID = Actions.FK_TypeID
```

If a match to `Actions` is not found to tie it with `Type`, then all columns in `Type` will be `NULL`.

[Here is a good graphical visualization of the different types of joins in SQL](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: What kind witchcraft is this?? it worked like a charm ;) thank you!

Comment: The "Witchcraft" is the join strategy.  +1 to Justin Pihony for showing a good use of "LEFT JOIN" where the first table referenced (the LEFT table) returns all results, while the right table is treated as NULLABLE.  This is exactly what the poster asked for.  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Use an OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT Actions.Date, Actions.Message, Type.TypeName 
FROM   Actions LEFT OUTER JOIN 
           Type ON Type.TypeID = Actions.FK_TypeID
```